# How to compare two items within Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to re-create GitHub version control for let's say posts. I've found a way to re-create an original post using duplicate AND another method to create a new post based on the original. Cool.

My issue is being able to display both the original and the new on the same page.

What I've attempted thus far is to just rely on the show method with having:

```
def show
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

Then in the view have in the form a checkbox to allow a user to select multiple posts, click a submit, and a new page renders displaying both side by side. Preferably showing the differences between the two but that's a wish list as I deal with this first.

Actually could I just simply do?:

```
def other_show
@post = Post.where(params[:id])
end
```

I also added in status as a boolean to help on the view for marking the checkbox. Would I then need to put something in the other_show method about the status?

Comment: I'm not fully understand, what you want to achieve. But if you want two posts on one page create `@var`s for both `Post`s in `show` method and layout them side-by-side in the view.

Comment: Actually that's what I really want is to see both posts on the one page. Ideally with seeing the differences between them. Would I do two vars in the show like: old_post = Post.find(params[:id]) and then new_post = Post.where(params[:id])?

Comment: In this case you'll get 2 identical posts. Your `show` route looks like `/posts/:id`, so controller will get this `:id`, but if you want to find another post and compare it with original one, you need to pass another param to route, e.g. `/posts/:id?compared_id=:another_id` and in show method `@original = Post.find(params[:id])` and `@compared = Post.find(params[:compared_id])`

Comment: For the route would I really just use: compared_id=:another_id? Or should it be something besides another_id?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show 2 different entities on one page you need to give `posts_controller` both `id`s.

Declare your `show` method like this:

```
def show
  @original = Post.find(params[:id])
  @compared = Post.find(params[:compared_id])
end
```

Correct route to this method will look like this:

```
/posts/:id?compared_id=:another_id
# Example: /posts/1?compared_id=2
```

To construct such a link in your view, you need to declare `link_to` method like this:

```
<%= link_to '1 <> 2', post_path(@post, compared_id: '2') %>
```

If you want to have a page where user can check 2 checkboxes for certain posts, you'll need to construct such href via Javascript.

But in fact I wouldn't suggest you to modify `show` method for such a task. It is better to use `show` method only for showing one entity from database. You can create another method, e.g. `compare` and pass both parameters there.

```
def compare
  @original = Post.find(params[:original_id])
  @compared = Post.find(params[:compared_id])
end
```

In `routes.rb`

```
resources :posts do
  get 'compare', on: :collection
end
```

It will give you helper `compare_posts_path`, which will lead to `/posts/compare` and you'll need to pass `original_id` and `compared_id` to it, like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Compare', compare_posts_path(original_id: 'some_id', compared_id: 'some_another_id') %>
```

It will result to

```
/posts/compare?original_id=some_id&compared_id=some_another_id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "recreate" some sort of version control I suggest you use something like the [audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited). Instead of building your own. From your example and comments it seems you don't have a clear relation between all related (versions of) posts.

Using this gem, each change to the Post content (for example, if configured properly) would be stored as an audit.

Showing the differences is a different problem. That's usually called a **diff** and you can find gems that do it for you, for example: [diffy](https://github.com/samg/diffy)

Comment: This is amazing and I wish I had these prior to all this code I've written. Thank you!

Comment: Writing code should be the least you do, the more you plan/research the less code you have to write and less code that can break. Good luck with your project!